# C# convert JSON to XML, but ignore some properties

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a JSON file that I need to convert to XML. I am able to get the conversion to work, using `Newtonsoft.Json` but I want to modify the node structure and eliminate some values. See below:

**Format of JSON input:**

```
{
"state": {
    "city": [{
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2",
        ...
        "property12": "value12"
    }]
}
```

}

**Using this code:**

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("input.json");
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

**Gives me this for XML:**

```
<root>
<state>
    <city>
        <property1>value1</property1>
        <property2>value2</property2>
        ...
        <property12>value12</property12>
    </city>
</state>
</root>
```

**But what I need is:**

```
<root>
<location>
    <property1>value1</property1>
    <property2>value2</property2>
    <property3>value3</property3>
</location>
</root>
```

I need to alter the structure of the output XML and select only some of the properties. How can I do this?

Comment: you're wanting to completely change the structure of the document.  You should read it into an object and manipulate the object before writing it back.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to parse your JSON into `JObject` and remove unwanted properties before converting it to XML, or remove nodes from XML before you write it into a file. Consider the following (verbose for clarity):

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("input.json");
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");

// Get nodes
XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("root");
XmlNode stateNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("state");
XmlNode cityNode = stateNode.SelectSingleNode("city");

// Remove unwanted "state" node
rootNode.RemoveChild(stateNode);

// Extract nodes you want to keep from "city" node
string[] propertyNames = { "property1", "property2" };
List<XmlNode> nodes = cityNode
    .ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Where(node => propertyNames.Contains(node.Name))
    .ToList();

// Add new "location" node and append 
XmlNode locationNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "location", null);
nodes.ForEach(node => locationNode.AppendChild(node));

// Append to root
rootNode.AppendChild(locationNode);

doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How would your example change is the "state" and "city" nodes were dynamic, i.e. actual state and city names? For example "AK" and "Anchorage". Is there a way to target the nodes position instead of actual name?

Comment: You need to get by name/id or iterate children of what-ever-is-parent-of-AK

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, you could convert only a portion of the json into XML.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("input.json");
var inputObj = JObject.Parse(json); // Parse the Json into a JObject
var properties = inputObj["state"]["city"] // Isolate the JArray

var locationObj = new JObject; // Create a new JObject to hold only what we want
locationObj.Add("location", properties); // Create a node called location and populate it with our JArray

var locationObjString = locationObj.ToString();

var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(locationObjString , "root");
doc.Save("output.xml");
```